# Trying to use CV approach in 500 training data to make prediction

Tags: r, prediction, cross-validation

[image: it just the first row in my training data set there all total 500 rows data set like this]

The picture above only show the first row of my training data set there are total 500 row like this.

Hi, I am tring to use cross validation approach to make a prediction about these datas. My question is how to using these data in CV approach.

I was trying something like the following:

```
library(caret)
data<-read.csv("trainingdata.csv")
train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)
grid <- expand.grid(.fL=c(0), .usekernel=c(FALSE))
model <- train(y~., data=data, trControl=train_control, method="nb", tuneGrid=grid)
```

Basically I want to include all the X in my model to predict f hat
I got "Error: wrong model type for regression" after execute the last line of the code. Where I need to change?

Comment: Could you add the data using `dput(data)` instead of a link? Much easier than following the link

Comment: Hi i edited my post please help.

Comment: The data is in a picture format and not sufficient to test what's causing the error. Anyway, what exactly are you predicting and why did you choose a naive Bayes?

Comment: Images are not a good way of posting data (or code). Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(data)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(data, 20))`.

Comment: Naive Bayes are generally not suited for regression analysis, why not use a different algorithm?

Comment: what other algorithm i should use?